# c# Regex question: only letters, numbers and a dot (2 to 20 chars) allowed

Tags: c#, regex

i am wrestling with my regex.
I want to allow only letters and numbers and a dot in a username, and 2 to 20 chars long
I thought of something like this

[0-9a-zA-Z]{2,20}

but then 21 chars is also ok, and that's not what i want

Comment: I think you need to be a little more explicit.  I doubt you want a username that consists of all dots.  I would think it would be more like `username` or `user.name` are allowed, but `user.`, `.user`, and `......` aren't.

Comment: I note that there are thousands of letters you are excluding. Is that intentional?

Comment: @tvanfosson well, it's admin functionality, so there will be a little thinking of the user too, but you're right, my algorithm doesn't restrict this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest that you make two checks -- one for length and one for content based on the fact that you probably only want one dot in the name, rather than any number of dots.  I'll assume that names like `username` and `user.name` are the only formats allowed.

This should get the content( but allows underscores as well):

```
^\w+(\.\w+)?$
```

If you don't want underscores, then you would use `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` in place of `\w+`.  To explain, it will match any string that consists of one or more word characters, followed by exactly 0 or 1 of a dot followed by one or more word characters.  It must also match the beginning and end of the string, i.e., no other characters are allowed in the string.

Then you only need to get the length with a simple length check.

Comment: very nice! yeah, the dot is a little difficult. ......... is probably bad, but j.p.van.der.bilt will probably be correct

Comment: @Michel - then you could change `(\.\w+)?` to `(\.\w+)*` to accept zero or more instead of zero or one.

Answer (score 8):

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\.]{2,20}$
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `^[\w\.]{2,20}$` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use start and end of string (`^` and `$`), and escape the `.`:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\.]{2,20}$
```